# Live-stream video from one android/ios phone to another android/ios phone

Tags: android, ios, video-streaming, webrtc, live-video

I have searched the internet for days now on how to implement a live video streaming feature from an android/ios phone to another android/ios phone (live video chat) but I can't seem to find anything useful. I looked on android developers for sample code, stackoverflow, google, android blogs but I can find nothing that I can borrow in my implementation.

I m looking for any solutions, with or without a server in the middle. I will prefer without but with a server in the middle will be OK too.

I think one good descriptive answer can be useful as it's seam many people are looking for this.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented real-time video streaming from one phone to multiple phones. It use a media server to be a mcu and broadcast the media stream in rtmp or hls format. You can find the client side source at the following position.
[reechat video conference solution](https://github.com/raymonwang/reechat_client)